# how to create an texture atlas of a 3d object in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization, textures, texture-atlas

I am working on a 3D game and it has lots of game objects in a scene. So I'm working on **reducing draw calls**. I'v used **mesh combining** on my static game objects. But my player is'n static and I can't use mesh combining on it. My player is nothing but combination of some cubes which uses the **standard shader** and some different **color Materials** on different parts. So I'm guessing, I can use **texture atlasing** on my player to reduce darw calls. But I don't know how to do it.

Is my theory of work right? If I'm right please help me with atlasing, and if I'm wrong please point out my fault.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Gamedev.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/59895/texture-atlasing-in-unity#answer-60022) ----- [pencilsquaregames.com](http://www.pencilsquaregames.com/2015/01/reducing-draw-calls-also-named-setpass-calls-on-unity5/) ----- [tracki.pl](http://tracki.pl/atlas3d/)

Comment: I often use `Photoshop` to combine all textures into one big texture and then use `3Ds Max -> UVW XForm Modifier` to shift the UVW coordinates but it requires you to have some basic knowledge about 3D modeling & Texturing. Anyway, your question is mainly about artist & 3D modeling not programming.

Comment: @CùĐứcHiếu
Thank you very much. But can you suggest me a simple way of UV mapping. My character is very simple (some connection of cubes). Any simple tutorial or blog might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Put all the required images into the same texture. Create a material from that texture. Apply the same material to all of the cubes making up you character. UV map all cubes to the relevant part of the texture (use UV offset in the Unity editor if the UV blocks are quite simple, otherwise you'll need to move the UV elements in your 3D modelling program).

Comment: thank you very much. But can you suggest me a simple way of UV mapping. My character is very simple (some connection of cubes). Any simple tutorial or blog might be helpful.

Comment: That entirely depends on what 3D modelling software you're using. There are hundreds of tutorials on the web for all the major softwares, just have a search. If what you mean is you don't have any modelling software then check out Blender (www.blender.org), it's free and very, very good.